# Vimscript: how to get current selected popup menuitem

Tags: popup, vim, popupmenu

You know, Vim can show popup-menu using &completefunc. Each menuitem is a dictionary with following items: 'word', 'abbr', 'menu', 'info', 'kind', 'icase', 'dup'.

How can i get what menuitem is selected at the moment?
I need to perform some actions when user selects some menuitem, and, so, i need to get the dictionary for this menuitem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this question is very tricky. You'll need to work asynchronously, override a few things, and interpret a temporarily inserted text.

I did answer a similar question on vim official mailing-list. (the title to search for is: [Custom Completion Function](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/6998a64e3bc293f4), the Message-ID is *b9811558-6ad0-44ba-a293-4e7fe24f84d2@zimbra60-e10.priv.proxad.net*)

Since then (2011) I've improved the code I've been using. I've described quite extensively the result on [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/dynamic-completion).